# Get class from div inside an li and add to same li

Tags: jquery

Get class from div inside an li and add to the same li.

The list items look similar to this:

```
<li class="original">
<div id="one" class="text">foo</div>
<div id="two" class="photo">foo</div>
<div id="three" class="video">foo</div>
</li>

<li class="original">
<div id="one" class="text">foo2</div>
<div id="two" class="photo">foo2</div>
<div id="three" class="video">foo2</div>
</li>

...
```

I need to grab the class from each of the list item's divs with an id of "three" and add it to the parent li's class. So, after the code runs the list will look like this:

```
<li class="original video">
<div id="one" class="text">foo</div>
<div id="two" class="photo">foo</div>
<div id="three" class="video">foo</div>
</li>

<li class="original text">
<div id="one" class="video">foo2</div>
<div id="two" class="photo">foo2</div>
<div id="three" class="text">foo2</div>
</li>
```

I tried something like this but it only updates the first list item:

```
$("#three").each(function(i) { 
    var newclass = $(this).attr("class");                   
   $(this).parent().addClass(newclass);
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can't have 2 elements with the same id, so correct this before trying anything else

Comment: yep.  you have broken elements and multiple id's with the same value.

Comment: the use of ID and class is reversed in this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are stuck with the repeating ID's

```
 $('[id="three"]').each(function(){  
     $(this).parent().addClass( this.className);

})
```

Comment: Yes, I am stuck with the repeating IDs (at least for now). And, yes, I may be new but certainly aware of that basic issue—should have noted. I just tried your approach and it appears to do the trick. Will test more. Thanks!

Comment: politically correct answer is to tell you to fix ID's...not always real world with legacy sites, or poor planning by others

Comment: since you're new here, start a good habit in approving answers

Comment: Will do. Questions too. Typos are dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple elements with the same ID.  In this case, jquery each is doing the correct thing and finding the first ID then stopping.  You can fix this by using the class instead:

```
<li class="original video"><div class="text one">foo</div></li>
<li><div class="photo two">foo</div></li>
<li><div class="video three">foo</div></li>

<li class="original"><div class="video one">foo2</div></li>
<li><div class="text two">foo2</div></li>
<li><div class="photo three">foo2</div></li>
```

Then the jquery:

```
$(".three").each(function(i) { 
var newclass = $(this).attr("class");                   
$(this).parent().addClass(newclass);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution you might want to take a look: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DnPrB/29/)

here is the JS code (After fixing the broken HTML issue people commented above but keeping the duplicate IDs)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.original').each(function(i) {
    var div = $(this).find('div').eq(2);
    var newclass = $(div).attr("class");                   
   $(this).addClass(newclass);
});
    });​
```